# Compiler generates "error CS1513: } expected", but } is there

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I am following a tutorial where I build my first 2D game in Unity.

I added a flipX function to flip my Sprite when I change my direction (pressing A or D)

I tried to use the same script, and tried to compile it there are 2 errors:

> Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(83,25): error CS1002: ; expected
> Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(83,25): error CS1513: } expected

I know what they mean and checked my script. I'm sure they are there where they are not. I just can't figure out the error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rigid;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpForce = 5.0f;
    private bool _resetJump = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 3.5f;

    private PlayerAnimation _playerAnim;
    private SpriteRenderer _playerSprite;
    
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _playerAnim = GetComponent<PlayerAnimation>();
        _playerSprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        Movement(); 
        
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        
        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            Flip(true);
        }
        
        else if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            Flip(false);
        }



        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded()  == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jump!");
            _rigid.velocity = new Vector2(_rigid.velocity.x, _jumpForce);
            StartCoroutine(ResetJumpRoutine());
        }

        _rigid.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * _speed, _rigid.velocity.y);
        _playerAnim.Move(horizontalInput);
    }
    
    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.6f, 1 << 8);

        if (hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if (_resetJump == false) 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void Flip(bool faceRight)
    {
       if (faceRight == true)
       {
           _playerSprite.flipX = false;
       }
       else if (faceRight == false)
       {
           _playerSprite,flipX = true;
       }
    }

    IEnumerator ResetJumpRoutine()
    {
        _resetJump = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        _resetJump = false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It would help if you added a comment to the code that indicated which line causes the error, so we don't have to count the lines to find line 85. The code editor highlights that line so it's easy for you to see, but unfortunately we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: `_playerSprite,flipX = true;` has a `,` instead of a `.` ... Note that you can simplify this entire method like `void Flip(bool faceRigt) { _playerSprite.flipX = !faceRight; }`

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple mistake, replace `_playerSprite,flipX = true;` with `_playerSprite.flipX = true;`.
You have a comma instead of a dot.

Comment: [Should I answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)